# Sounds like a couple of PSE users, if you ask me

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

"'Oomph?'"
"Nice! One More?"
"Aha, 'Trickle!'"
"Oh, Pretty one! Everything's intensely auditory!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A crack at this:

> **onomatopoeia** - which the first letters of each word spells. The words contain many examples.

Oomph

> Oomph, ooh (contained) and moo (reversed).

Trickle

> Trickle and tick (contained).

Aha

> Aha, ah & ha (both contained or reversed).

Oh

> At least ho (reversed), oh doesn't show in this [onomatopoeia](http://www.onomatopoeialist.com/onomatopoeia-h/) list, but sounds like one.

A bash at the title: Sounds like a couple of PSE users, if you ask me

> Posers  - if you ask me - are puzzle setters - and this sounds somewhat like PSE users.

Comment: That works. The title was just a "sounds like" clue to your answer word.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if I am answering this correctly, but...

> Are these descriptions of PSE users names?

"Aha, 'Trickle!'"

> [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain) I found this by thinking of the title referring to PSE user and trickle is what rain does.

"Oh, Pretty one! Everything's intensely auditory!"

> [Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36023/bass) I found this by the title and bass is an instruments that makes noise and bass is a "pretty" fish?

Working on the others....

Comment: While I'm quite curious to see what you come up with for more usernames in this puzzle, this is not the answer.